# How can I get the path of NMAKE Makefile?

Tags: makefile, nmake

In order to support building an EXE file from any directory, I would like to make my paths relative to the location of the Makefile.

While I know how to do so with [GNU Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/):

> $([dir](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-dir) $([realpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-realpath-1) $([lastword](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-lastword) $([MAKEFILE_LIST](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029)))))

How can I get the path of [Microsoft NMAKE Makefile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN)? Is it even possible to achieve the same behavior?

I know that the Makefile variable [`MAKEDIR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/special-nmake-macros?view=msvc-170#-recursion-macros) can give me the path from where the nmake command was executed, and that at the `nmake` command the [`/F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/running-nmake?view=msvc-170#nmake-options) variable holds the path from there to the location of the Makefile, but I don't know how to access the value of `/F` inside the Makefile in order to combine the two.

(Please don't suggest me to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) instead.)

Answer (score -3):

Using the `$(MAKEFLAGS)` macro, you can access the value of the `/F` option, which specifies the path to the `Makefile`.

**Example**

```
# Extract the path from MAKEFLAGS and assign it to MAKEFILE_PATH
!IF "$(MAKEFLAGS)" != "" && "$(MAKEFLAGS)" != "-"
MAKEFILE_PATH = $(subst /,$(NULL),$(dir $(patsubst /F:,%,$(findstring /F:,$(MAKEFLAGS)))))
!ENDIF

# Set the default value of MAKEFILE_PATH if it's empty
!IFNDEF MAKEFILE_PATH
MAKEFILE_PATH = .
!ENDIF

# Usage example: combine MAKEFILE_PATH with other paths
SOME_DIR = $(MAKEFILE_PATH)\some\directory

# Print the value of MAKEFILE_PATH for verification
all:
    @echo $(MAKEFILE_PATH)
```

Comment: `fatal error U1104: Unknown text function 'dir'.`, replacing `dir` with `abspath`/`basename` returns an empty variable.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is mentioned in the [NMAKE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/special-nmake-macros?view=msvc-170#-recursion-macros): "`MAKEFLAGS` Options currently in effect. Use as `/$(MAKEFLAGS)`. The `/F` option isn't included."

Comment: Hi, Sreeram Nair.  

Most or all of your last 11 answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Many also have comments indicating that they are wrong in some respect. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.